# Passing class params using a laravel config file

Tags: php, html, laravel, tailwind-css

I have made a config file in Laravel (Please pull me up if this is not an appropriate use case for config files):

```
<?php

return array(

    'nav' => array(
        'bg-color' => 'text-red-500',
    ),


);
```

I'm am using this variable in my blade template:

```
<?php 
 $navConfigs = Config::get('theme.nav');

?>

<nav class="{{$navConfigs['bg-color']}}"> ....</nav>
```

Now,
This sometimes works - I can't seem to quite pinpoint what makes it work, I do know if it works then I change a value it stops, possibly something to do with caching?

The value is being passed across when you view the page source you can see the class had been added correctly. However, sometimes tailwind will act like its not there and revert to defaults

Additionally, if I set the value on the blade template it works 100% of the time so it is definitely related to loading the values from the config.

Apologies if it's something silly but I'm tearing my hair out over here.

Comment: Ensure you're clearing your caches with `php artisan optimize:clear` after making changes. Your sample code is missing quotes around the class name, and also around the array index. I hope your live code is not like that? You should rename your config value to remove the hyphen and then simply do `<nav class="{{ config('theme.nav.bgcolor') }}">`

Comment: Sorry, just a mistype from rewriting my code out in isolation. Yes, I have run `php artisan optimize:clear` every time to no avail.

Comment: Ok you've updated the code but there are still missing quotes on the array index. It should be `<nav class="{{$navConfigs['bg-color']}}">`. But again I'd suggest just calling the `config()` helper directly in the blade template.

Comment: Sorry - another mistype that is not reflected in my code.  I tried calling it directly earlier on and ran into the same issue however I will try this again for coverage sake. What's the reasoning why calling it directly is any different from setting it first?

Comment: It's just generally frowned upon to have raw PHP code in your Blade templates at all, and the helper function is what's typically used by Laravel itself as well as projects using it. Another useful feature of the `config()` helper is you can set a default value. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-config

Comment: When it seems not to be working, check the HTML (i.e. view source in your browser) to see what is being output for the nav element.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As mentioned in the post - The page source is displayed correctly every time. Then when a config value is changed - this change is reflected in the page source but the visual CSS is not visually displayed. E.g if I change `text-red-500` to `text-blue-200` the new value is correctly displayed in the page source but the color shown reverts to defaults (black).

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. All I can suggest then is using the browser's inspector to check the element when it isn't working. Could be some other CSS rule overriding it.